# How to find a polynomial with $f(1), f(4),f(9)$ prime and coefficients in $\{1,2,3...10\}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials

How to find a polynomial with $f(1), f(4),f(9)$ prime and coefficients in $\{1,2,3...10\}$? I can't think of any way on how to generate such types of polynomials? Also, would they have a minimum degree, that is such polynomials couldn't have degree less than some $n$?

Comment: surely a constant polynomial $f(x) = 5$ does the job. Why don't you admit $0$ as a coefficient?

Comment: @Crostul For that reason exactly.

Comment: @NorthKorean What reason? Constant polynomials still work.

Comment: I doubt there is a clever systematic way to do it, because the coefficient condition is essentially arbitrary.

Comment: All coefficients of the powers of $x$ of degree bigger than the degree of the polynomial are $0$, so it not clear to me which coefficients should be $\neq 0$.

Comment: The polynomial $5$ is a polynomial whose polynomial function evaluated at $1, 4$ and $9$ yields a prime and whose coefficients are all in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. How is this not an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: By brute force, there are 4 constants, 6 linear, 32 quadratic, 186 cubic and 1109 quartic polynomials that meet the requirement. there doesn't seem to be any obvious pattern among them.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $2$, $5$ and $11$ are all prime.

(For that matter, you could just take a constant function whose value is prime...)

Comment: I am sorry, but it was actually $f(9)$.

Answer (score 1):

If it is linear, the coefficient of $x$ has to be even.  Try $f(n)=2n+k$, for odd values of $k$.